# Getting a Segmentation fault (core dumped) message when trying to execute my gui program

Tags: c, gtk, glade

Here is my code right now

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gtk/gtkx.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

GtkWidget* window;
GtkWidget* fixed;
GtkWidget* menu;
GtkWidget* file;
GtkWidget* open;
GtkBuilder* builder;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

        gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
        builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("gui.glade");
        window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window"));
        g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
        gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

        fixed = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "fixed"));
        menu = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "menu"));
        file = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "file"));
        open = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "open"));

        gtk_widget_show(window);
        gtk_main();

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If I remove the initialization for the widget open and the statement where I pull it out from builder, the program executes fine but with it in there I get the Segmentation fault. I tried stepping through it with gdb, but it hasn't helped.

Comment: Would you mind adding your UI file as well? I think this might hold the clue to answering this question

Comment: Also, you are using `gtk_builder_connect_signals` but there is no signal handler in your code. I'm pretty sure the error is in the code you did not post.